# Need to upload a single file across 2 load balanced servers

Tags: php, linux, apache, file-upload, load-balancing

Currently my company has a 3 server set-up. 2 web boxes behind a load-balancer and another box not behind the load-balancer (used for Admin, CMS and stats). Due to the state of funds at the moment we are looking to decommission our single box which is not behind the load-balancer. The box has our CMS on it and a media subdomain points to /home/web/media on that box. The problem is if we remove the box and port all the code (PHP) over to the load-balanced web boxes, then when a file is uploaded in the CMS it will only upload it to the media directory of the box the user hits. So if a user hits web1 and uploads a file that file will only be accessible in the /home/web/media directory of web1. So we need to somehow rsync the /media directories on both web1 and web2 when a file is uploaded. Or do something else.

What would you recommend to be the best way to accomplish this?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Just for information purposes we are running PHP 5.2, Red Hat Enterprise Linux and Apache 2.0.52

Regards,

Owen

Comment: Rsync could work, but it would require a cron or some kind of trigger, and its not really "pretts" think about using SMB ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block ) or NFS  Mount Points ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System_(protocol) ). However you do it, there is no easy Solution

Comment: Until recently, we had a number of servers which did this via rsync triggered via cron. It was a problem for us too, so for that reason (and a number of others) we moved to a SAN file system which is shared between the servers. End of problem.... Although quite pricey.

Answer (score 3):

You have a few choices (some have been already mentioned):

- Store uploaded files in a database (not recommended for files you will need fast random access to).
- Use a network filesystem such as NFS or SMB, and store uploaded files there. (You can also have code copy uploaded file to the other server's filesystem exposed over NFS or SMB).
- Use a clustered filesystem such as GFS or OCFS.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't it an idea to use a network share for the media, so you can make it available on both servers at all time?

Comment: it would be really slow without a way of caching..plus it kinda breaks the point of having 2 machines, in case one of them dies

Comment: @Quamis if you keep the network storage away from both machines and separated, with scheduled off-site backups, you're already one step further. As for caching, you could use a CDN that has a (short) cache time. Good disks and network connections help as well. There are probably a lot of other different options as well.. This is just one of them that I'd imagine..

Answer (score 0):

```
    function scp($username, $host, $port = 22, $file, $destination){

        $dirs = explode("/", $destination);
        array_pop($dirs);
        $dirs = implode("/", $dirs);

//         die("\nscp ".$file." ".$username."@".$host.":".$dirs);

         system("ssh ".$username."@".$host." mkdir -p ".$dirs);
         system("scp ".$file." ".$username."@".$host.":".$destination);
    }
```

of course you need that www-data has its public key on both servers and write privileges

Answer (score 0):

If you want the file uploaded to both servers in realtime, just do that.

1. User uploads a file on `server1`.
2. `server1` process the upload and stores it in `server1/media`.
3. `server1` makes an authenticated request to `server2/api/uploadFile` (curl)
4. `server2` process the upload and stores it in `server2/media`.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: The idle question will be like how to upload files to server 1. While uploading from PHP file, we dont know which server the file will be uploaded right?

Comment: Another problem is that one server will eventually fail. The upload will not happen on the server that failed. When it is up again, the file will not be available on the server.